# How to update node version in gitlab CI using labels

Tags: node.js, versioning, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab and it's CI for deployment of a node app. I can't seem to find an easy way to update the version on deployment based off an MR's labels.

Ex. I create an MR and add the label 'minor'. How can I call 'npm version minor' in the gitlab yml?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What part is problematic for you, seting up good filter/triger condition, or is that the `npm version minor` itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your MR labels with `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS` in your gitlab-ci.yml. This will return a list of labels, so I don't know the format you will get.

in your script :

> npm version $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS

I did not test it, but you can give it a try.

You can see complete predefined environment variables [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)